# html_theme_options vs. html_logo in conf.py using alabaster

Tags: configuration, python-sphinx

hello all experienced Sphinx users,

since a few days I'm performing my first experiences with Sphinx for building a small documentation site. I'm playing around using the Alabaster theme. When I try to place a logo in the left upper corner it only works with using an entry in the build configuration file 'conf.py' like this:

```
html_logo = '_static/images/PJS-small.png'
```

when I try to use the Alabaster theme configuration like this

```
html_theme_options = { 
    'logo': '_static/images/PJS-small.png',
    'logo_name': True,
    'description': 'one more logo'
}
```

no logo appears above the sidebar.

I'd like to use the theme configurations because I'm able to place a subtitle and other things like that.

Does anyone have an idea how to use the Alabaster configurations like it is documented?

Thank you very much for helping.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Alabaster installation instructions](http://alabaster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html),
you have to add an `html_sidebars` setting to the `conf.py` file:

```
html_sidebars = {
    '**': [
        'about.html',
        'navigation.html',
        'relations.html',
        'searchbox.html',
        'donate.html',
    ]
}
```

This causes Alabaster’s customized sidebar templates to be loaded.

Then you can specify the logo path like this:

```
html_theme_options = { 
    'logo': 'images/PJS-small.png',
    # etc.
}
```

The path is automatically prepended with `_static/`.

Answer (score 0):

In the theme configuration (`theme.conf`) file, you need to use the following syntax:

```
logo = images/PJS-small.png
logo_name = true
description = one more logo
```

Note the absence of the `_static` directory in the logo path (it is prepended in the theme's HTML template) and the *lowercase* boolean.

Still, you can set any theme configuration variable through the `html_theme_options` object in the Sphinx project configuration file (`conf.py`).